# Adding new columns in pandas to data frame to create columns that calculate total sum and the relative abundance using assign?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set that has a column that contains the  type of taxa in a  group eg archea and cyanobacteria , and the other columns that represent my samples eg a1,a2,a3, and in every cell I have the total numbers of organisms.

I am trying to create new columns that contain the sum of all the  values for each column A1 and A2 and so on, and then a new columns that contain a calculated relative abundance; so that every number in the cell is multiply  by 100 and divide by the total sum of the entire column. I want to determine the relative abundances of taxon groups in each sample.

My code so far:

```
for i in table:
new_name='p_'+ i
table=table.assign(new_name=table[i]*100/table[i].sum())
print i, new_name
```

I get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Any suggestions and comments will help  a lot!
Thank you

Comment: um.... how is your data stored? are you using pandas? if so please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40667266/edit) to add the [tag:pandas] tag so people with the relevant information can find your question.

Comment: yes i am using pandas.I will do that. Thanks

Comment: from context I'd guess that `table[i]*100` returns a string and `table[i].sum()` returns a string and you are trying to divide them which doesn't make sense, not familiar enough with pandas to suggest a fix but you could start by printing out those two values to see if they are what you expected (I'd assume it isn't)

Comment: Hi Tadhg McDonald-Jensen, thanks you for your suggestion. I was able to get it to work!